# positioning <span> tag in side <div> tag

Tags: html

i'm designing with div and span tag & i have created table by using these two tages. I want to set the position of the particular span inside the div . how to do this?

below is my design

```
 <html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div style="margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;">
   <div style="height:30px;">
   <span class="name">A.B. Enterprises</span>
   <span>(42100001)</span>
   <span>OS : Cr.</span>
    <span style="float:right; left:0px; top:0px;position:relative;">
   <span><img src='C:/Documents and Settings/priyanka/Desktop/BlueColor.gif' alt="" /></span>
    <span ><img src='C:/Documents and Settings/priyanka/Desktop/BlueColor.gif' alt="" /></span>
    <span><img src='C:/Documents and Settings/priyanka/Desktop/BlueColor.gif' alt="" /></span>
   <span><img src='C:/Documents and Settings/priyanka/Desktop/BlueColor.gif' alt="" /></span>
   </span>   
   </div>
   <div>
   <span>Supriya Dye Chem</span>
   <span>Turn Over : Cr.</span>
   </div>
   <div>
   <span>Indrabhan Pandey</span>
   <span>(Mumbai1</span><span>,Mumbai1)</span>
   </div>
   <div><hr /></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks

Comment: post you html code, so that we can able to answer your question

Comment: 1. Make a precise question, say what effect you are not managing to get. 2. Post the generated HTML code, rather than the unprocessed ASP source.

Answer (score 4):

```
<div style="position:relative;">
 <span style="position:absolute: top:0px; left:0px;"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to be safe, at the end of the position style, you should read: `position:absolute;` (with a semi-colon instead of a colon)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="your_div">
    <span style="float:left; left:0px; top:2px;"></span>
</div>
```

You can set the position playing with 'left' and 'top' values

Comment: yes i tried it, It aligns exactly what i want but. It shifts my span element below from top of div. After that it looks like it is in the next div.

Comment: play with the top value, i.e. try a negative value

Comment: try adding position:relative; to the span's style.

Comment: ...and make sure the span tag is inside the div... this is a common error

Comment: yes it is in div tag. I added code which is generated by browser.